# My harddrive failed SMART check and short drive self test. What should I do?

Tags: hard-drive, hard-drive-failure

I used SeaTools for Windows to test my harddrive and i failed the S.M.A.R.T check and Short Drive Self Test.

1. What's wrong with my hard drive?
2. Is it a big problem? Do I need to do anything to solve the problem?
3. (if I save a file and open it and it wasn't as i have saved it earlier, i would consider that a very big problem indeed)

Comment: See [here](http://superuser.com/questions/248686/what-are-targeted-read-test-smart-short-self-test-what-do-failures-of-them-mea) for more info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Back up everything you can from that drive, and then replace it.   Short Test errors can sometimes be fixed, but [SMART](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) errors are usually permanent (an over-all SMART threshold for some error count has been exceeded).

Comment: you mean **permanent** as it's not a problem i can ever fix by applying a format or something, or by using a special software or something?

Comment: I mean permanent as it's not a problem you can ever fix. :)

Answer (score 5):

Based on the information provided, I cannot tell you what is wrong, but you should certainly replace the drive if you care about anything on it. Your drive is predicting failure, so I would consider that a big problem.

You should also check to see if it is still under warranty. Depending on the drive, a 3-year or 5-year warranty would probably apply directly from Seagate if it is not OEM. Otherwise, you would need to contact the OEM for warranty replacement.

Comment: you mean it's not a problem i can fix by applying a format or something, or by using a software or something?

Comment: it is under warranty

Comment: That is correct. At least some of those errors are permanent and are predictive of failure. They are not intended to tell you about something you can fix, but of the drive actually failing.